# Can a courtyard be used to describe a place that doesn't have plants?

Tags: word-usage, synonyms

I am trying to describe an area like a square, but it is not square shaped. I was wondering if a courtyard is an appropriate word to use because I have seen people use it but when I tried to google it to see what results I would get. The places I found all had trees, so I was wondering if people imagine a place with plants when courtyard is used and what other word could be used to describe an area that is like a square but is not square shaped.

The place I am talking about is 400,800 square meters including the building the surrounds the area, I don't know how big the courtyard is but I know that it is huge, I apologize if that is not helpful, but I really don't know.

I don't know how to explain it, but it is like a square, and it doesn't have plants. It is a place that is open in the middle of the building where people can sit and relax or even play, but it is not square shaped.

[image]

This is a link to the place I am trying to talk about: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Mosque_of_Mecca

[image Wikipedia]

Comment: How big is the place (is it measured in hectares or in square meters)? How is it used?

Comment: A courtyard _may have_ plants, but the defining criteria are "An unroofed area that is completely or partially enclosed by walls or buildings, typically one forming part of a castle or large house." [-OLD](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/courtyard)

Comment: There are lots of similar words: *plaza*, *yard*, *parade ground*, *park*, *light well*, etc. But we can't say which one works in your situation without more context.

Comment: "Huge" isn't much help. Is it huge like Times Square, or huge like Nebraska?

Comment: I don't know how to explain it, but it is like a square, and it doesn't have plants. It is a place that is open in the middle of the building where people can sit and relax or even play, but it is not square shaped.

Comment: It's definitely bigger than times square but not as big as Nebraska.

Comment: You are talking about an enclosed area 634 meters each side! That's bigger than the Kremlin.  So where is it? Please post a link so we can see what you are talking about.

Comment: I've seen the space referred to as the 'Inner Court'. This can be used of large buildings of all kinds (provided they have an inner courtyard!) But there's no rule that you have to call it something else if a keen gardener brings a few nice plants in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A courtyard is an area that is largely surrounded, usually by some building complex. The word that you might be searching for describing a large square that is not necessarily square-shaped could be the word "plaza". If the space has more the feeling of being inside (i.e. with some sort of roof), the correct word would be "atrium".

So, if you don't find the words "plaza" or "atrium" more appropriate, I would stick with the word "courtyard", which doesn't have to signify a small area per se. If you are uncertain about the topic of vegetation, just have a look at this explanation on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Courtyard) where the main picture has no vegetation. Although courtyards often have some vegetation, it's not what defines a courtyard. Also, a courtyard doesn't have to be square-shaped.

> This is a link to the place I am trying to talk about
>   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Mosque_of_Mecca

Yes, the area just around the Kaaba is a courtyard.